# How add week dates in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My target is to add real week dates in one column in format 01.12 - 07.01. No year needed. Is that any kind of formula for automatically adding those real dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell A1 write date which your week dates begin and put this formula into cell A2 and fill down using mouse:

```
=DAY($A$1-WEEKDAY($A$1;2)+1+((COUNTA($A$1:A1)-1)*7))&"."&MONTH($A$1-WEEKDAY($A$1;2)+1+((COUNTA($A$1:A1)-1)*7))&"-"&DAY($A$1-WEEKDAY($A$1;2)+7+((COUNTA($A$1:A1)-1)*7))&"."&MONTH($A$1-WEEKDAY($A$1;2)+7+((COUNTA($A$1:A1)-1)*7))
```

In `WEEKDAY()` function number 2 is which week starts from **Monday**. You can change it to 1 if your week starts from **Sunday**.

Or download and check my [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aii5Sgn6uT4zIPkrYc3CMeLkKII6aedPElBYJmxlDm4)

Comment: I got enter 17.10 - 23.10 in A1. I copy/paste your code in A2 and I get: Function WEEKDAY parameter 1 expects number values. But '17.10 - 23.10' is a a text and cannot be coerced to a number

Comment: I have successfully added a date in A1, but I want dates to be auto fill in A3, A4, A5... this solutions works only for A2

Comment: No it isn't. Just fill down this formula to get results. Press black plus sign with mouse at the right bottom corner of cell B2, keep pressing and go down.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to do that in Google sheets but there is no plus. Does that should works in Google sheets?

Comment: I mean Microsoft Excel with local excel file

Comment: I have add 10.10.2017 in A1. When I add formula in A2 I get "There is a problem with this formula. Not trying to typa a formula? When a first character is = or - excel thinks it's a formula"

Comment: Can you please steps to produce this?

Comment: It's a bit complicated and may be long. To see how it works select cell A2, open Formulas tab from Excel ribbon and press "Evaluate formula". Then you can see steps of calculation. And please accept my answer if your probem solved :)

Comment: How to make it works for lines to 30 also? What must I do

Comment: recheck your website, everything is correct. 09/10/2017-16/10/2017

Comment: To get week dates for other rows, download file, open with MS Excel and fill down using mouse. If you do not know what is filling down, search in google.

Comment: January 9, 2017 - January 15, 2017 is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my formula, please change 8 s in formula to 7.

Comment: One thing left before to accept and vote up that answer. Just please explain how to add more rows that automatically filled

Comment: OK, Do you use MS office excel? There is a gif example: http://trumpexcel.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/How-to-use-Fill-Handle-in-Excel-Weekday-Names.gif and explanation here: http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2003/creating-complex-formulas/5/

Comment: And for google sheets: http://vuiwe9e6yv-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Fill-Down-Google-Sheets.gif

Comment: In your sheet formula is proper but, here - not. Please correct it.

Comment: Is there an option to delete first row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127815/discussion-between-bzimor-and-teodorkolev).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure what your reference numbers are, so forgive me if this is unhelpful, but parhaps try using the =weeknum() function